# int object not callable error

Tags: python

I'm trying this example:

[image]

```
p = 10000
n = 12
r = 8
t = int(input("Enter the number of months the money will be compounded "))

a = p (1 + (r/n)) ** n,t

print (a)
```

.. but the error is:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Is Python seeing p as a function? If so, is there no way I could do it without importing modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using python 3..

```
p = 10000
n = 12
r = 8
t = int(input("Enter the number of months the money will be compounded: "))

a = p * (1 + (r / n)) ** (n * t)

print(a)
```

Also double check the units for `t`, is it in months or years?  The formula seems to suggest years (if `n = 12` is months per year) but you are prompting for months.

If in python 2.x you would need to import division from `__future__`, or convert r to float first.  And you would use `raw_input` for the prompt.

Comment: input works, but not raw_input `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`

Answer (score 5):

Change the line to

```
a = p * (1 + (r/n)) ** (n * t)
```

Python doesn't interpret variables that are next to each other as being multiplied (nor would it interpret `n, t` as that.

Comment: Note: If the OP is using python 3 (which they seem to be given the print function syntax), then division is sane by default and `//` is integer division.

Comment: also i think the p should be OUTSIDE of the exponent.

Comment: An alternative to `float(r)/n` is to use `from __future__ import division` before any other imports.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to multiply by p, so you should be explicit and use a `*`:

```
a = p * ((1 + (float(r)/n)) ** n,t)
```

Cast to float (thanks David R) to prevent int rounding problems in division.

Answer (score -1):

1. you need the "*" operator to multiply numbers
2. dividing int by int does not give a float so cast one to a float multiply of divide by a float (you will see "*1." in some code to do this"
3. your input line does not match the variables above (i.e. t should be years not months and n is number of times compounded per year ... 12 for monthly and 4 for quarterly etc)
4. also need to change your 8 to .08 as a percentage

Try:

```
p * (1 + (r/100.0/n)) ** (n * t)
```

Comment: A down vote?.. My only gripe is that the most upvoted and the accepted answers don't give the right answer with the variable inputs provided.  Doesn't being right count any more?..... now you've got something to down vote....hit me ... LOL